# Drag drop between two forms with two datagridviews c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have recently finished my drag drop event between two `datagridviews` on my `main form`, and it works well. Now, however, I have decided to make a change that requires `datagridview2` to be on another form (`form2`). Can anyone tell me how to drag drop between two `datagridviews`, while on separate `forms`?

Below is my existing code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
        {
            Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex].Value = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void dataGridView2_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
            dataGridView2.DoDragDrop(
               dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .Cells[e.ColumnIndex]
                            .Value.ToString(),
               DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I my opinion drag and drop between two different forms work same like on one form. Are you sure that dataGridView1 property AllowDrop is set to True?